How to use div control ID inside the *ngIf
I am trying to use div control id inside the *ngIf. My div is as follows
<div class="table table-bordered fare-table" *ngIf="brandeddiv.id=='branded1'" [id]="'branded'+indexOfelement"  #brandeddiv>

I want to display the div when the div id is equal to 'branded1'.
But I am taking below error

Property 'brandeddiv' does not exist on type 'DataComponent'

Please let me know how to correct the issue.
Thanks in advance.
.

why not *ngIf="indexOfelement==1"? You can not use a template reference variable before it's created. NOTE: In general in Angular you rarely need change the "id", using ViewChild or ViewChildren should solve your problem.
